# Ajuda com JQuery + Php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tenho um formulário que é é carregado através de um while do bd.
a estrutura é essa:

```
<form id="formulario" name="formulario" action="javascript:Func()" method="post"> 
  <div id="div_prod"> 
    <?php $sql_prod = mysql_query("SELECT bla bla bla"); 
    while($sql= mysql_fetch_object($sql_prod )) { ; ?>  
      <input name="a" id="a" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sql->a; ?>">
      <input name="b" id="b" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sql->b; ?>">
      <input name="c" id="c" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sql->c; ?>">
      <button type="submit"><?php echo $sql->a; ?></button> <?php }; ?>
  </div>
</form>
```

Ou Seja, os inputs de nome a, b e c são gerados n vezes, conforme a quantidade de registros que retorna do select.

Ai, tenho uma função que adiciona os resultados no mysql, conforme abaixo.

```
$("#formulario").submit(function() {
        var a = $("#a").val();
        var b = $("#b").val();
        var c = $("#c").val();
        $.post('../scripts/arquivo.php', {a: a, b: b, c: c}, function(resposta){ 
       if (resposta != false) {
            $("#status").html(resposta);
       } else {
            $("#status").html("Inserção realizada com sucesso!");
       }
});
```

O processo esta funcionando ok, porém, sempre carrega somente o primeiro produto do while.

Já tentei colocar as variáveis com name e id [] (ex: , mas não envia nada e não dá erro nenhum.

Deixando sem os [] só envia o primeiro ítem.

Como resolvo isso?

Comment: Poste a estrutura da consulta em PHP, provavelmente o erro esta nela

Comment: Olá Marcelo. Obrigado pelo retorno.  
Acabei de editar o post para ficar mais fácil o entendimento.

Comment: Primeira dica, troque a extensão (obsoleta) `mysql` por `mysqli` ou `pdo`

Comment: Certo. Alterado. Obrigado.
Isso influência só no caso de diferentes versões do PHP, correto?

Comment: Como esta seu código agora?

Comment: Mesma coisa.. só alterei o mysql por mysqli

Comment: uma boa prática seria você utilizar, no lugar de setar cada input numa variável, a função `serialize()` do jQuery, ficaria mais ou menos assim: `var dados = $(this).serialize();` e colocar o name dos seus inputs como array. Após isso, basta fazer a tratativa correta no arquivo *../scripts/arquivo.php* para fazer a inserção no banco.

Comment: Não tenho a mínima idéia de como fazer :/

Answer (score 0):

A propriedade id somente vai ser utilizada no navegador, porém name sim será usada para montar os dados do request, com certeza você precisa passar como um array, neste caso usando, por exemplo: `name = "a[]"`.

Porém note que seu script PHP, no lado do servidor, que está recebendo este request para salvar no banco, precisa ser alterado para receber os parâmetros no formato de array.

**Edit**

Para a manipulação da id com jquery, você pode definir dinamicamente as ids de acordo com um valor de referência, que pode ser um índice, dentro do while você faria algo assim:

```
$i++;
<input name="a" id="a<?php echo '_' . $i; ?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sql->a; ?>">
<input name="b" id="b<?php echo '_' . $i; ?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sql->b; ?>">
<input name="c" id="c<?php echo '_' . $i; ?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sql->c; ?>">
```

Comment: Olá Amigo.
Já tentei fazer isso e quanto a isso, tranquilo. Porém, a duvida é se terá vários inputs com a id=a, qual o parametro que passo para o jquery reconhecer a id que eu quero, pois independente de qual eu clicar, sempre vai pegar a primeira id do while.

Comment: Ok, entendi, veja a alteração da resposta

Comment: Fiz as alterações sugeridas. Agora, ao invés de mandar somente o primeiro registro, ele manda todos no array.
Preciso que dispare somente os dados do id_8 (por exemplo).

Comment: Aí entra sua lógica de no momento do post em ajax capturar somente o id desejado, difícil ajudar com mais código sem saber qual a regra de decisão para escolher o id

Comment: Esquece o meu código então.. se possível, claro, me dê um exemplo de vários buttons e mandar somente o button que eu clicar pelo Jquery. Pra mim funciona 100% mas só se eu tiver um único produto na listagem. Para usar o serialize, o que eu percebi é que ele manda tudo os inputs da page e não somente o que eu cliente, o que não funciona no meu caso, pois quero somente 1 produto específico da listagem e não todos que estão na listagem.

Comment: Não vou conseguir montar um exemplo para você antes de segunda, mas pelo que descreveu, uma outra ideia é montar um form para cada item hidden mais o botão correspondente, ainda com os índices de nome como explicado, neste botão ou tag a você dispara uma chamada onClick para a função que irá manipular este request ao servidor.

Comment: Obrigado amigo pelo apoio.
Consegui resolver com os passos deste link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380588/how-to-post-data-from-php-while-loop-with-ajax

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Se vc repete o id dos arrais n vezes, ele só irá pegar a primeira vez.

O problema está pq vc está passando para o ajax, somente os valores dos inputs com ids a, b e c.  Então ele só irá interpretar os 3 primeiros.  vc pode fazer isso:

```
$("#formulario").submit(function() {
    var dados = $(this).serialize(); //pega todos os inputs e transforma em query string
    $.post('../scripts/arquivo.php', dados, function(resposta){ 
   if (resposta != false) {
        $("#status").html(resposta);
   } else {
        $("#status").html("Inserção realizada com sucesso!");
   }
});
```

e no seu html vc pode seguir o exemplo do Ademir Mazer, e tratar os valores da forma que achar melhor no seu scripts/arquivo.php:

```
<input name="a" id="a<?php echo '_' . $i; ?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sql->a; ?>">
<input name="b" id="b<?php echo '_' . $i; ?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sql->b; ?>">
<input name="c" id="c<?php echo '_' . $i; ?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sql->c; ?>">
```